# INI File Parser in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm learning Haskell at the moment, and have just written my first useful module - a parser fo INI files. I used Parsec. I'd like to know what can be improved here - or maybe I did some things completely wrong and there is a better way. Thanks.

```
module IniFile (iniFileToMap) where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Char


parseIniFile :: Parser ([(String, [(String, String)])])
parseSection :: Parser (String, [(String, String)])
parseSectionHeader :: Parser String
parseNameValue :: Parser (String, String)
parseComment :: Parser ()
parseNormalValue :: Parser String
parseQuotedValue :: Parser String
parseValue :: Parser String
parseName :: Parser String
parseInsideQuotes :: Parser String
parseCmtOrSpace :: Parser ()
iniFileToMap :: FilePath -> IO (Map.Map String (Map.Map String String))

parseCmtOrSpace = do{
   spaces;
   skipMany parseComment;
}

parseInsideQuotes = many (noneOf "\"")

parseQuotedValue = between (char '"') (char '"') parseInsideQuotes 

parseNormalValue = many1 (satisfy (\c -> isPrint c && not (isSpace c)))

parseValue = parseQuotedValue <|> parseNormalValue

parseName =  many1 (satisfy (\c -> isAlpha c || isDigit c || c == '_' || c == '.'));

parseComment = do{
   skipMany1 (char ';');
   skipMany (noneOf "\n");
   spaces;
}

parseNameValue = do{
   name <-  parseName;
   between (skipMany (oneOf " \t")) (skipMany (oneOf " \t")) (char '=');
   value <- parseValue;
   return (name, value);
}

parseSectionHeader = do{
   name <- between (char '[') (char ']') parseName;
   return name;
}

parseSection = do{
   name <- between parseCmtOrSpace parseCmtOrSpace parseSectionHeader;
   values <- endBy1 (parseNameValue) (parseCmtOrSpace);
   return (name, values);
}

parseIniFile  = do{
   result <- many1 (parseSection);
   return result;
}

list2Map list = Map.fromList (map (\e -> (fst e, Map.fromList (snd e))) list)

iniFileToMap path = do{
   result <- parseFromFile parseIniFile path;
      case (result) of
         Left err -> error (show err)
         Right xs -> return (list2Map(xs));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that you have grouped all the type signatures together, away from the function bodies. This seems very strange to me. It's way more common (and as far as I'm concerned also way more readable) to have a value's type directly before its definition.

The second thing I noticed were all the braces and semicolons. Unless you have a specific reason to use them, I'd strongly recommend making use of Haskell's significant indentation instead. Much less visual noise. I'm especially confused by the semicolon at the end of `parseName`'s definition as `parseName` doesn't use `do`-notation and you didn't use a semicolon on any other definition which didn't use `do`.

---

You sometimes surround variables with parentheses (e.g. in `values <- endBy1 (parseNameValue) (parseCmtOrSpace)`, but not in the line `name <- between parseCmtOrSpace ...` directly above it). I can't see any system to when you do this and when you don't, so it just seems random and inconsistent. So I'd recommend to get rid of the needless parentheses.

Speaking of parentheses, you might also want to get rid of some more parentheses by sprinkling a couple of `$` signs in your code, to give it a more "haskellish" feel.

---

```
parseSectionHeader = do{
   name <- between (char '[') (char ']') parseName;
   return name;
}

parseIniFile  = do{
   result <- many1 (parseSection);
   return result;
}
```

Whenever you have something of the form:

```
foo <- bar
return foo
```

You can simply just write `bar`. I.e.:

```
parseSectionHeader = between (char '[') (char ']') parseName

parseIniFile  = many1 parseSection
```

---

```
iniFileToMap path = do{
   result <- parseFromFile parseIniFile path;
      case (result) of
         Left err -> error (show err)
         Right xs -> return (list2Map(xs));
}
```

Here the indentation is off - `case` should not be indented further than `result <-`. It should be:

```
iniFileToMap path = do
    result <- parseFromFile parseIniFile path
    case result of
        Left err -> error $ show err
        Right xs -> return $ list2Map xs
```

Answer (score 2):

**Formatting/Conventions**

Firstly, the usual convention is to alias Data.Map as M. Usually qualified imports are one letter, unless you need two because of a collision.

Don't use braces except for record syntax.

Don't use semicolons.

**Monads**

Alot of your do notation doesn't need do notation. To add to sepp2k's examples, we also have stuff like:

```
parseCmtOrSpace = do
   spaces
   skipMany parseComment
```

which should be written much more nicely as

```
parseCmtOrSpace = spaces >> skipMany parseComment
```

since do notation is usually not necessary for a two line do.

As another example of cleaning up do notation: (This one is significantly more to personal case than my other example. However it also makes some other changes that you should look at, even if you want to keep your monadic do notation, such as refactoring out the tabs)

```
parseNameValue = do
   name <-  parseName
   between (skipMany (oneOf " \t")) (skipMany (oneOf " \t")) (char '=')
   value <- parseValue
   return (name, value)
```

We can instead write: (I apologize if the following is incorrect, I don't have a compiler available)

```
parseNameValue = liftM3 g parseName eq parseValue
   where eq = between ts ts $ char '='
         ts = skipMany $ oneOf " \t"
         g x _ y = (x, y)
```

We can do the same for `parseSection`:

```
parseSection = do
   name <- between parseCmtOrSpace parseCmtOrSpace parseSectionHeader
   values <- endBy1 (parseNameValue) (parseCmtOrSpace)
   return (name, values)
```

becomes

```
parseSection = liftM2 g names values
    where names = between parseCmtOrSpace parseCmtOrSpace parseSectionHeader
          values = endBy1 parseNameValue parseCmtOrSpace
          g x y = (x, y)
```

**Parsec**

You should define a way to get an `Either ParseError (M.Map String String)` instead of erroring in the library. Erroring should be left to the client. Although you may want to provide one that provides an `Either`, and one function that errors automatically.

It seems to be convention that the monads that build up the parser should not begin with parse. We see this in the Parsec library (its `char`, not `parseChar`). The functions don't parse; they return data that can be used for parsing. At the very least do `nameValueParser`, but theres nothing wrong with just `nameValue`. Just don't export the functions and there won't be any namespacing issues most of the time.

Comment: You can create stunningly readable Parsec code by using its Applicative instance. For example, `parseNameValue` then becomes

    `parseNameValue = (,) <$> parseName <*> (ws *> char '=' <* ws) *> parseValue`

(where `ws = skipMany $ oneOf " \t"`)